# How to distribute java components for developers to use?

Tags: java, .net

I am not sure how to put the correct title.

but here is the brief explanation.

With Microsoft .NET, i created a server side custom control using C# to be used in ASP.NET pages. I distribute the DLL generated as a component. developers will include that and use in their ASP.NET project.

Likewise, how can i do for Java based web components for to use with JSP or JSF or any other java web frameworks?

Answer (score 4):

This is normally done via [jar files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) and in enterprise applications mostly in conjunction with the 'dependency resolution manager' [maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maven)

Note that there are other package formats like osgi bundle, nbm, ear or war but the atomic most common bundle is jar

Comment: I didn't say that this is the simplest method but it is the most common in enterprise. And I only added this to the answer for further information. I think jar-file is already the answer.
Not that there are a lot more build tools for java, if you are interested take a look at this picture I made some time ago: http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/evolution-of-build-systems/